# Set value and string in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

this question might be very basic. But I just want to make this clear:

lets say I have a code like :

```
string currentToner = (string)((Hashtable)ht[1])["value"];
string maxToner = (string)((Hashtable)ht[2])["value"];
```

Now I want to set this value in data grid view.

```
int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = currentToner."/".maxToner;  //-->this is not the correct way.
```

How to set the value so that it looks something like:

```
5000/10000
```

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = currentToner + "/" + maxToner;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it the PHP way, in C# string concatenation is done with plus signs

```
dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = currentToner + "/" + maxToner;
```

You can  format the string as well

```
dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = string.Format("{0}/{1}", currentToner, maxToner);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a `string`, set a `string` as the value :

```
dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = currentToner + "/" + maxToner;
```